# Limit of a real sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let

$$x_{n}=\frac{1}{n+2^{0}}+\frac{1}{n+2^{1}}+...+\frac{1}{n+2^{n}}\quad (n\in\mathbb{N}, \text{ }n\geq 1).$$

What is the limit of $x_n$?

**Attempt:**  Just the boundedness, $x_n∈(0,2)$, $\forall n\geq 1$. Can not even determine the monotonicity.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Have you tried computing, say, $x_1$ up to $x_{10}$ explicitly?

Comment: Hint: try splitting the sum into two chunks. One but not the only split point that works would be at the $\sqrt n$th term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
x_n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac1{n+2^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\log_2(n)} \dfrac1{n+2^k}+\sum_{k>\log_2(n)}^n \dfrac1{n+2^k}\\
&\lt\sum_{k=0}^{\log_2(n)} \dfrac1{n}+\sum_{k>\log_2(n)}^n \dfrac1{2\cdot 2^k}\\
&\lt \dfrac{\log_2(n)+1}{n}+\dfrac1{n}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is an interesting idea, but... why $\sum_{k>\log _{2}\left( n\right) }^{n}\frac{1}{n+2^{k}}<\sum_{k>\log _{2}\left( n\right) }^{n}\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^{k} }<\frac{1}{n}$ holds$?$ I think that $\sum_{k>\log _{2}\left( n\right) }^{n} \frac{1}{n+2^{k}}<\sum_{k>\log _{2}\left( n\right) }^{n}\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}\left( n-\log _{2}\left( n\right) +1\right) \leq \frac{n+1}{2n}.$

Comment: I removed the $n$, not the $2^k$. That made it a geometric sequence.

Comment: Ok, with a small remark. If one removes the $n$, I think the second sum is less than $\sum _{k>\log_{2}(n)}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k}}<\frac{2}{n}$.

Comment: But then there's the factor of 2. It doesn't really matter, since all that is needed is to go to 0.

Answer (score 2):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Since @marty cohen already provided the good solution and the upper bound, I shall just report here some results we obtained in my former research group a few decades ago working the most general problem
$$x_n^{(a)}=\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac1{n+a^k}\qquad \text{where} \qquad a >1$$

The general formula is given by
$$x_n^{(a)}=\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{a}}^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log (-n)}{\log (a)}\right)-\psi
   _{\frac{1}{a}}^{(0)}\left(n+1-\frac{\log (-n)}{\log (a)}\right)}{n \log (a)}$$ where appears the [q-polygamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) which is related to [Lambert series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html).

As good *approximation* was proposed (from some deep arguments)

$$x_n^{(a)}=\frac {\alpha_a+(1-\beta_a) \log(n)}{n \log(a)}$$ where $\alpha_a <1$ increases and $\beta_a$ is a small number which decrease when $a$ increases.

For the specific case of $a=2$, $\alpha_2 \sim 0.3877$ and $\beta_2\sim 0.0063$.

Comment: Nice work. Glad to see that my $\log(n)/n$ is the correct order of magnitude.